# Factor with reference level in R?

Tags: r

In R there are factors and there are ordered factors. Is there anything "in between", so to speak? factors are completely unordered, while ordered factors are completely ordered; I want a factor type that has a reference level. This would be useful in tagging a control group, for instance, that I always want to consider as a "baseline".

I have seen `relevel()` in R, but this is not what I want, since there is no way (apparently) to tell the difference between a factor whose reference level is the first level, and a regular factor.

Does anyone know how to tag a reference level in R, or if not, how I can extend the factor class to do so?

Comment: Can you please show us an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: You may explore the case of factor with specified order `factor(0:4, levels = c(3,4,0,1,2))`. Note this is different of ordered factor or unordred factor.

Comment: @agstudy, this doesn't work, because as I said, there is no way to tell the difference between a factor in the default order and a factor with a reference level.

Comment: Did you look at the answer from @NealFultz ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the reference group using `contrasts`. For example, to set the contrast so that `group2` is the reference in `sleep`, I would do this:

Without the contrast, group1 is the reference group.

```
> lm(extra~group, sleep)

Call:
lm(formula = extra ~ group, data = sleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       group2  
       0.75         1.58
```

With the contrast set:

```
> contrasts(sleep$group) <- contr.treatment(nlevels(sleep$group), base=2)
> lm(extra~group, sleep)

Call:
lm(formula = extra ~ group, data = sleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       group1  
       2.33        -1.58
```

EDIT:

Based on the comment below, the reference level is stored implicitly, but it is easy to retrieve if you know what to look for. The reference group will be in the rows on the contrasts and but not the columns. Try this:

```
> reference_group <- function(x) do.call(setdiff, dimnames(contrasts(x)))
> reference_group(sleep$group)
[1] "2"
```

Comment: Coming back to this 6 years later, I note that someone asked above whether I had seen this answer. So I thought I'd add a note to explain why I never accepted this. The question was about having the information *in* the factor (e.g., because it is inherent to the interpretation of the levels). Contrasts don't do that.

Comment: I tried to answer your question by writing a function that outputs the reference group.